# OBIEE TOPN On Result of Union Two SubjectArea

Tags: obiee

I used **"Union"** to combine two different subject area in an analysis in **OBIEE 11** :

**"A"** is a column in the **first subject area**  with formula that needs 
**"A_Dim"** to be calculated using "A_Dim" and Case-When (So I Should Use "A_Dim" in first subject area then exclude it in result)

**"A"** equals to **zero** in **second subject area**

**"B"** is a column in the **second subject area**

**"B"** equals to **zero** in **first subject area**

**"C"** is a column in **Result** (Using **Add Result Column**) that has this formula :

**SUM("A" BY sth ) / SUM("B" BY sth)**

("A","B",... replaced with saw_i in result column formula as you know)

the problem is, I can not get **top 10 rows ordering by "C"** ??

(I tried using RANK, TOPN , TOPN(RANK()),... with no luck)

(and one more thing, there are two problem with using "Narrative view" instead of other views , first they want a bar chart, besides in narrative there is no Exclude option and I should use javaScript to get top 10 from thousands of repeated "C" values)

Comment: Core question: Why a union?! Are you not able to properly model things in the RPD?

Comment: The data I need in this case ,are from different subject areas , there is no way to combine this two subject areas outside the OBIEE (one of the subject areas come from an OLAP cube and the other one come from an ORACLE DB) so is there any other way than using UNION ?

Comment: Just because the data is sourced from different storage technologies does not mean that you can't create a unified model. Generally as soon as you choose to do a union you must accept a loss in functionality.

Answer (score 1):

The original question is old, but I figured I would add my solution in case anyone ends up here like I did.

I was able to create a "Result Column" with my TOPN formula. I did not have to create equivalent columns in the two queries that are being unioned (aka there are 4 columns in each union query but 5 columns in the "Result Columns" overall). It seems to work as expected.